# Set shopping cart price rule for shipping according to product size in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to set a shopping cart price rule for shipping where shipping cost can be charges according to product size in Magento 1.9.
For example, there is a product attribute 'product size' and it has 3 values, "heavy", "medium", "small". So I want to set a shipping rule in which a "Heavy" product should be charged $50, "medium" $30 and "Small" $15.
How can I create a shopping cart price rule for such a condition? And please also tell me about how to set the condition for it in the shopping cart price rule.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What technology have you used to implement the shopping cart?

Comment: I am using magento 1.9

Comment: You need to provide such details in the post. Also put tag magento in question because people who know magento have it in their favorite tags and sometimes look only for questions with tag `magento`. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok. is there any solution of this question..??

Comment: I don't know, I have never used magento.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
In the admin panel, go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes, then open custom attribute('product size' in your case). Under Frontend Properties, set **Use for Promo Rule Conditions** to **Yes**. This will allow you to use your attribute in the shopping cart price rules.

Step 2:
Create a new rule. In condition tab, first select 'product attribute combination' under that in the selection box you should see your attribute 'product size', select that and then give the values for same.